# xelatex Hangs with 100% CPU usage when using it with the switch: -interaction=batchmode and select error messages

Tags: xetex

I have been running xelatex on many `.tex` files some of which may contain syntax errors. I will be handling errors by checking the return code of `xelatex`. This works well most of the time in that when `xelatex` would normally output an error message that requires user input to terminate by typing `X`. After which xelatex will terminate and return one, however, I have ran into an issues in which `xelatex` will go into an infinite loop instead of terminating and returning a non zero exit status (the expected behavior).

Example of an error message that triggered the problem (what I get when I run `xelatex` without the `-interaction` switch):

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

I only want to fix the infinite loop issue. I do not want to fix the syntax error. How do I prevent `xelatex` from going into what appears to be an infinite loop when there is an error?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  You should post a minimum working example.

Comment: note that it is provably impossible to detect all cases that a program has an infinite loop "the halting problem"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle While I appreciate your help I shall note that I am not interested in detecting infinite loops. I just want xelatex to terminate on all errors instead of most errors like it does now.

Comment: You want to do it from within the process itself? There's the `-halt-on-error` switch. Otherwise, among the GNU coreutils there's [`timeout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html). However, I'm having trouble reconciling the final paragraph and your comment from a few minutes ago, so I'm not sure which to suggest.

Comment: @jon yes I wanted to do this within the process itself and the -halt-on-error parameter seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing that out. I am not in the process of doing some extensive testing and I will update soon.

Comment: xetex's error behaviour is somewhat constrained by compatibility with tex's (which won't change) which means that in practice you have a better chance of (trying to) avoid the error conditions than to change the actual error behaviour. Although it's a bit hard given the fragment of information in the question to see exactly which looping error you have.

Comment: I have conducted some tests today and the -halt-on-error switch did resolve the issue.